# Android Studio isn't updating the versionCode

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle

I've been facing a serious problem lately with Android Studio, where the `versionCode` specified in the `build.gradle` file is not taken into account.

It happened twice now, and the first time it just worked for no reason after countless tries. It's either this or the *Google Developer Console* has some sort of bug which doesn't correctly detect the versionCode.

I tried editing it manually as well as with the build flavors, I always get an error message from Google when trying to upload the update, specifying the old `versionCode`.
(I am also changing the versionName)

Comment: what file are you updating the versionCode in? app.gradle or mainfest?

Comment: that would be app.gradle

Comment: Post your build.gradle

Answer (score 0):

You have to update both **versionCode & versionName** to higher values